# Can iBeacon scan iOS devices even bluetooth is off?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

iBeacon/sensor tags should scan the devices that enters my store and report some information to the server/device. Information like device name, what position and how much time customer spent at particular product. My questions are:

1. Can iBeacons scan the device(IOS bluetooth smart ready devices) even if bluetooth is switched off?
2. If not, what should replacement i have to use for it.

Comment: Can my cellphone receive calls when it's off? Of course not! Neither can an iOS device detect beacons when Bluetooth is turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iBeacon is an open protocol built on top of BLE. An iBeacon is a send-only device, and a beacon receiver is a receive-only device.

Beacons send a very short ID signal, usually once a second. That is ALL they do. Period.

The beacon in your store has no knowledge of the iOS devices that come into it's range. Beacons don't scan for anything.

It would be possible to have your user's apps transmitting iBeacon signals constantly, but only if the app was running constantly in the foreground. That would drain the user's battery quickly, and if the user switches to Angry Birds or to the phone app, your app would stop transmitting. Also, with privacy concerns you are likely to get pushback from customers on broadcasting a constant "I, John Doe, am right **here**. Feel free to track my every move!" signal.

That said, there's nothing preventing you from developing an app that uses iBeacons plus other non-iBeacon BLE, or plus the internet and web services.

You could write an app that monitors for your store's iBeacons, and when it detects one, it sends a local notification to the user to wake up the app (if the phone was asleep) and also sends a message to your store's server (over the cell data network) with the user's ID and the beacon they found. You could use that information to send push notifications back to the user ("Special on ladies' watches on isle 12!")

Our company specializes in iOS development and have a sub-specialty in this sort of app. We'd be happy to talk further if you'd like to pursue it.

Comment: Thanks Duncan , So According to your statement I can say we cant get information from user without their acknowledgement(pushbacks from customer)

Comment: @JAI, right. Apple goes to great lengths to make sure that it's iOS users must "opt in" before their information is sent to outsiders

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. This helps me to take first step in to my project. Please help me if i need some clarifications at some time.

Answer (score 7):

If the Bluetooth is off then how can the iBeacon even see the device. So no this is not possible. And no you can not see the device any other way, wel maybe with some GSM/WiFi detector but you will never be able to the device name or something.

Also the iBeacon is transmitting an identifier that the users device is picking up, so I don't think you iBeacon will be able to to detect any device since the protocol should then work the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My next question is If bluetooth is on in my client device whether i can get basic information what i mentioned above without paring the device. I am beginner so please do correct me if my question is wrong.

Comment: Bluetooth (BT) Low Energy (BLE) is different from "regular" Bluetooth. You don't have to pair the way you do for a BT headset, say.

Comment: Oh great to here that.